# Why does invoking "tail" on ArrayBuffer take linear time?

Tags: scala, data-structures

Check: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html

It says ArrayBuffer takes linear time when requesting tail. However, it is much faster when appending

My understanding is that an ArrayBuffer is simply a dynamic array.

How come appending is amortised constant time but getting the last element takes linear time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tail` is *not the last element*, it is all elements but the first. You want `last`.

```
Seq('a', 'b', 'c').head  // 'a'
Seq('a', 'b', 'c').tail  // Seq('b', 'c')
Seq('a', 'b', 'c').init  // Seq('a', 'b')
Seq('a', 'b', 'c').last  // 'c'
```

Comment: pffft, I think I need to have breakfast. Thank you !